# Make default date selection April of 2012

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation, date

The earliest record I'm searching is from 4/2012 so I'd like the default selection when the page is first loaded to be that.  2012 is the first entry in option list, it's making April appear first that is the issue

Here's my current php code for two select boxes, one for month and one for year.

```
    <form class="formtext" action="monthly_sums.php" method="get">
    <p>Monthly Report<br></p>
        Company:
            <select class="bck1" name="company" id="company">
                <?php echo $options ?>
            </select><br>
        Month:
            <select class="bck1" name="month" id="month" onchange="" size="1">
                <option value="01">January</option>
                <option value="02">February</option>
                <option value="03">March</option>
                <option value="04">April</option>
                <option value="05">May</option>
                <option value="06">June</option>
                <option value="07">July</option>
                <option value="08">August</option>
                <option value="09">September</option>
                <option value="10">October</option>
                <option value="11">November</option>
                <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>
        Year: 
            <select class="bck1" name="year" id="year" onchange="" size="1">
                <?php echo $options2 ?>
            </select>
        <input type="submit" class="submit" onClick="return monthlyValidation()"/>
    </form>
```

and here's my php for the year option list:

```
    //propagate year selection range for monthly report. from 2012 to current year
    $curr_year=date("Y");
    for($i=2012;$i<=$curr_year;$i++)
    {
        $options2 .= "<option value =\"".$i."\">".$i."</option>";
    }
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using JQuery Library?

Comment: I am not getting your issue. What is your issue? I guess i have solution but can not understand your issue well.

Comment: @divy3993 my issue is that when the page loads January 2012 is the displayed, but I want April 2012 displayed in the select boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `selected="selected"` attribute on the 'April'-`<option>` to make April selected on loading the page. Or use a JavaScript init function to set the correct option as selected.

Comment: what would be the javascript method?

Comment: You can use `document.getElementById("month").options[ index ].selected = "selected"` to selected the right option if I'm correct. index should be 3 in this case (for the 4th option)

Comment: But the first solution (inserting the attribute in the PHP) is better.

Comment: @MKasper You're welcome, don't forget to mark it as the answer if it helped you ;)